# Defining singleton-like container objects... and keeping tslint happy

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a large TypeScript project and have recently added tslint in order to enforce some basic code styling rules. This has largely been painless, but there is one things that I'm still questioning.

I have a few bits of code where I have a singleton-like object which wraps some properties and functions. Imagine something like:

```
function open(x) {...};
function close(x) {...};
let isOpen = false;

export const MainMenu {
    open,
    close,
    isOpen
};
```

But the problem is that tslint complains about the naming of MainMenu because I've told it to enforce camelCase variable names. In all circumstances but this, the convention holds true and in situations like this, I think it's right to be upper-case (`Math`, `Reflect`, etc. all follow this convention).

So what should I do here? I could either disable the rule whenever this occurs, or perhaps the `namespace` concept is more appropriate for this? But then I'm using external modules, so I don't know if I should. Plus, `namespace`-s make it more difficult to add property members.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: There's no Calculator in the code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my example as MainMenu made slightly more sense in this context! Now updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this seems more like an area where I'd use `namespace` (or perhaps a separate external module? Then in your current module you could re-export it.)

But let's say you do want to do things this way, and you want to make TSLint happy. Your easiest solution is to just temporarily disable `variable-name`:

```
/* tslint:disable:variable-name */
export const MainMenu {
    open,
    close,
    isOpen
};
/* tslint:enable:variable-name */
```

(Note that you could move the re-enabling comment up a few lines - I just prefer it where I have it for aesthetic purposes.)

There's also a current feature request [for a way to exclude specific variables from this rule](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/522) in your `tslint.json` file. So down the road that might be an option!

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking through a few GitHub repositories to see how others handle this, and many (including Microsoft, in VSCode) seem to be using `namespace` so I think I'll look into going down that route.